# How to correctly implement a REST service that returns a list of images using Spring MVC\Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am not so into RESTful web services and I have the following doubt about how correctly return a list of image using RESTful paradigm.

I am working on a Spring Batch application (but it is the same thing that uses Spring MVC for this purpose). I have this controller method that returns to the client a list of images as **a list of array of byte converted into a JSON message**.

I implemented it in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getAllImagesByRoomId",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> getAllImagesByRoomId(Long roomId) throws DataAccessException {

    log.debug("getAllImagesByRoomId START");

    List<byte[]> result = roomMediaService.getRoomImageListById(roomId);

    log.debug(result.toString());

    log.debug("getAllImagesByRoomId END");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);

}
```

It works pretty fine and my client retrieve the images from the returned JSON.

But from what I have understand it is not RESTful conception because in the REST principals I have to return a JSON response which contains hyperlinks to all the individual images, and then the client can follow those links and grab the images.

So in this case I will have a service handle request to a single image (represented by an URL) and that return an image as an array of byte. but for the service that return a list of images I have my REST service that return a list of URI represented the single image served by the first service.

Could be a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

### [Spring Data REST](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/)

What is and isn't Restful is constantly debated.  Generally speaking, it involves Stateless HTTP requests that target a particular resources, via URI, and the response usually conforms to JSON.  Not all of these are hard and fast rules but that is what you'll typically see.

An improvement on the above approach is HATEOAS, which are the links you referred to.

You can easily generate Restful, HATEOAS endpoints via the **Spring Data REST** project.  It handles most of the painful configuration and lets you focus on the resources you wish to expose.

Comment: Tnx, but do you think that the approch that I am using at this time could be considered REST? Or not?

Comment: IMHO the endpoint you've designed doesn't conform to the popular conventions of Rest APIs.  You would typically see it organized by resource (e.g. /images, /images/{id}, /images?roomId={roomId}, etc.)  That's one area for improvement.

Comment: Tnx, I will take it into consideration to improve my services